# Rollback reason

Tags: feature-request, editing, moderation, answer-invalidation

Quite often I roll back the edit because the code was edited after the answer was posted. In such situation I feel obliged to post a comment why did I rolled it back. Not a biggie, but annoying. Can we address the situation? I can think of two ways:

- Lock the question as soon as it is answered. Sound a bit too drastic.
- Provide a radio button with a rollback reason, and post the reason as a comment.

Thoughts?

Comment: Locking would prevent more answers from coming in. That would be inconvenient.

Comment: @Mast "Locking" is a bad word indeed. I meant locking edits; I don't know if there is such a capability (I suspect not), so maybe the question is about implementing one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> - Lock the question as soon as it is answered. Sound a bit too drastic.

Locking is a moderator tool with good reason. For one the lock mechanism implemented by SE currently only allows **completely** locking a post, which would preclude any subsequent answers.
As it currently stands this is not feasible, especially since there are valid reasons for editing a post after an answer has been posted. Not all edits touch the code and not even all code edits are actually invalidating.

> - Provide a radio button with a rollback reason, and post the reason as a comment.

IIUC the only thing that makes this different from what you're currently doing (assuming you're using something like [AutoReviewComments SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/)) is that the comment is hard-baked into the UI. I don't think that's something we really want either, considering that rolling back an edit is a pretty unusual thing to happen to users on the internet. Allowing just the extra touch of "a human did this" can make a lot of difference in how that interaction is received.

Overall I can really understand that posting rollback comments over and over is annoying, but there are existing tools to make this less annoying and adding a "built-in" to the system seems to not provide a lot of benefit...